# Уникальные идентификаторы для полей/свойств

Tags: c#, list, словари

Я хотел бы сделать приложение для обсчета химических параметров веществ (и их смесей), и у меня есть вот такая структура для индивидуального компонента:

```
struct Component
{
    string Name { get; }
    double MoleFraction { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

И есть класс уравнения, которое использует какой-то набор параметров. У каждого компонента эти параметры есть (они берутся из базы данных).

```
class Equation 
{
    private Dictionary<Component, double> omega;
    private Dictionary<Component, Pressure> Pc;
    private Dictionary<Component, Temperature> Tc;
}
```

Можно ли как-то по другому реализовать привязку параметра к компоненту, кроме как через Dictionary? Хотелось бы примерно такого же поведения, как у ключа в SQL, чтобы он также еще и не мог повторяться. Как-то так я бы хотел, чтобы можно было получать значения этих параметров:

```
Console.WriteLine(
    omega("Methane"));
Console.WriteLine(
    Pc("Hydrogen"));
```

Я просто до этого работал с Aspen Custom Modeler (там в качестве языка используется своя модификация VisualBasic), там можно указывать, по каким параметрам можно получить доступ к значению

```
Component As StringSet (["Hydrogen", "Methane"]);    // тут указываем, какие будут идентификаторы компонентов
Phase As StringSet (["Vapor", "Liquid"]);            // тут указываем, какие будут идентификаторы фазы компонента (пар, жидкость)
Omega(Component, Phase) As RealVariable;             // объявляем переменную

// И вот таким образом ее можно использовать
Omega("Hydrogen", "Vapor") = 100;
Omega("Methane", "Liquid") = Omega("Hydrogen", "Vapor") * 10;
```

Comment: А что вам мешает сделать параметры компонента свойствами объекта `Component`, а параметры среды, в которой происходит моделируемая реакция, вынести в свойства уравнения `Equation`?

Comment: Ну там в каждом уравнении свои параметры - то их 2, то 11, не хотелось бы их таскать каждый раз. Хотя может придется как-то так и сделать. А с параметрами среды у меня так и было.

Comment: стоп, сколько параметров используется в уравнении это одно и оно ни как не зависит от количества параметров химического компонента. Другой вопрос, что компонент придется чуть более вдумчиво делать с учетом взаимной зависимости некоторых параметров, в том числе и от параметров среды. Я не силен в химии, но понимаю, что даже у простой воды состояние зависит от температуры и давления. Так что лишними они не будут, но надо предусмотреть значения по-умолчанию, для случаев, когда параметр не задан явно. Если прям хочется переменный список - используйте словарь параметров компонента внутри компонента

Comment: я просто сам пока задачу возможно криво поставил, в принципе вопрос можно свести до "а как мне в С# сделать это так же, как было в другой программе". но я так понял, вы имели в виду, что свойства компонента лучше прописать в `struct Component`, а параметры уравнения в `class Equation` - это хорошая идея, и пока я наверное так и сделаю